# Setting Public Property Values on the Command Line

Tags: powershell, wix, windows-installer, parameter-passing, quoting

[Setting Public Property Values on the Command Line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Msi/setting-public-property-values-on-the-command-line) of an msi follows the pattern

```
MyInstaller.msi PUBLICPROPERTY="someValue"
```

This works on "Command Prompt" aka cmd.exe and powershell.

But

```
MyInstaller.msi PUBLICPROPERTY=""
```

does not work like expected in powershell. I expected that it sets PUBLICPROPERTY to null but it sets PUBLICPROPERTY to the value "CURRENTDIRECTORY="C:\temp\msi\"" (it does work like expected with cmd.exe).

Why do powershell and cmd.exe behaviour different, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: I was going to add a comment, but now I see an answer already. Let me just add that in addition to trying `PUBLICPROPERTY=\`"\`"`, I think you can assign: `PUBLICPROPERTY="{}"` to set the property to nothing. Just shooting from the hip, not tested.

Comment: That was macht first guess too and: no: that does not Work. The brackets get written as value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**PowerShell, on Windows of necessity, performs *re-quoting*** of your arguments behind the scenes.

**This invisible re-quoting doesn't always work as expected**, such as in this case.

***Update***:

- In [*PowerShell (Core)*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) **v7.3+** the **techniques below - except for `--%` - no longer work *by default***, and require you to (temporarily) set [`$PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#psnativecommandargumentpassing) `= 'Legacy'` first - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74440425/45375) for details.

You can solve the problem by **tweaking your quoting**:

```
... PUBLICPROPERTY=`"`"  # `-escape the " chars.

... 'PUBLICPROPERTY=""'  # use enclosing '...', so " chars. can be used as-is
```

Note that using `'...'` won't work if you want to include the values of PowerShell variables / expressions in the argument.

Additionally, in PSv3+ you can use [**`--%`, the stop-parsing symbol**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing), to make PowerShell **pass the remaining arguments through as-is, as if you had called from `cmd.exe` / a batch file** (including expansion of environment-variable references such as `%OS%`).

```
... --% PUBLICPROPERTY=""
```

Again, you won't be able to reference PowerShell variables or expressions in the arguments that way.

---

As for what happens *without* the techniques above:

- `PUBLICPROPERTY="someValue"` becomes
  `PUBLICPROPERTY=someValue`
- `PUBLICPROPERTY="some Value"`, due to whitespace, becomes
  `"PUBLICPROPERTY=some Value"`, i.e., the *entire argument* is enclosed in `"..."`.

PowerShell-*internally* an argument such as `PUBLICPROPERTY="someValue"` has its quotes *stripped*: if you pass such an argument to a PowerShell cmdlet or function, it will see just `PUBLICPROPERTY=someValue`.

On passing such a value on to an *external program*, PowerShell decides *situationally* whether double-quoting is needed, but that quoting is then only ever applied to the *entire argument* - the initial placement of the `"` chars. is lost.

Thus, `PUBLICPROPERTY="someValue"` turns into `PUBLICPROPERTY=someValue` and is passed on *as-is*, because it *contains no embedded whitespace*, so PowerShell applies no double-quoting.

By contrast, `PUBLICPROPERTY="some Value"` turns into `PUBLICPROPERTY=some Value`, which is passed on as `"PUBLICPROPERTY=some Value"`, because the presence of whitespace requires double-quoting in order to preserve the value as a single argument.

Note that **PowerShell only ever applies *double*-quoting to arguments passed to external programs**, because that is the only style of quoting that can be assumed to be understood by all programs.

The re-quoting logic has changed over time and has [**bugs, which, regrettably, are here to stay**](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/2361#issuecomment-384945346) due to backward compatibility concerns.

E.g, `'3 " of rain'` becomes `"3 " of rain"`, which is *broken*, because the *embedded `"` lacks escaping*; the workaround is to anticipate that and explicitly do what PowerShell should be doing *automatically*: escape the embedded `"` as `\"` for the benefit of the external program: `'3 \" of rain'`