# passing exclamation, brackets as part of executable arguments in powershell

Tags: powershell, syntax, command-line-arguments

In git, if we want to exclude a file from diff output (on bash) we do something like follows:

```
git diff -- !(file.txt)
```

But this is disallowed in powershell. Hence is there a way to achieve this in the powershell prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply *single-quote* your argument:

```
git diff -- '!(file.txt)'
```

Single-quoting makes PowerShell treat the string literally and prevents it from interpreting chars. such as `(` as its own metacharacters.

Before invoking the target program, PowerShell *re-quotes arguments if and as needed*, behind the scenes; that is:

- It encloses an argument in `"..."` if it contains whitespace, and also in certain, less common scenarios (see link below).
- It passes it *without* quotes otherwise.

Note: There are pitfalls associated with this invisible re-quoting - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51773694/45375).