# How to pass a string constant as it is in powershell

Tags: java, string, powershell, arguments

I have the following simple java program:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Arguments
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        System.out.println("args: "+Arrays.toString(args));
    }
}
```

When I execute this in powershell using the following command: `java Arguments "*.java"` the string received in the program is not `"*.java"` but a comma-separated list of all java files in the current directory. And if there are no java files in the current directory the string received is `"*.java"`.

I want to know why this is happening and how to pass a string as it is without converting it.

Update: `java Arguments '"*".java'` and `` java Arguments `"*.java`" `` did the work but this creates the same problem when executed in cmd. Can anyone explain why this is happening? Is there any common solution for both PowerShell and cmd?

Comment: This sounds like `java.exe` globbing the files, can you try with `'*.java'` instead (single-quotes)

Comment: still the same with '*.java'

Comment: you should run a jar file using -jar option. something like this: `java -jar Arguments "*.java"`

Comment: @epcpu cant the program run without creating a jar file? I tried making one and executed it .but its giving me `Unable to access jarfile Arguments` error

Comment: Have you tried to escape the quotes with a grave-accent (add grave-accents directly before each of the double quotes)?

Comment: @DBADon yes backticking the double quotes ie, \`"*.java\`" also works.thanks.but then the string is passed as `\`*.java\`` in cmd not `*.java`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: Indeed it is `java.exe` that performs the globbing, but `'*.java'` won't help that; PowerShell passes both `'*.java'` and `"*.java"` as `*.java` (no quotes) to external programs; only something like `'"*.java"'` would work (on Windows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is *not* PowerShell (nor `cmd.exe`) that interprets `"*.java"` as a filename pattern and expands (resolves) it to the matching files, known as *globbing* in the Unix world.

(You would only get that behavior if you used `*.java` - i.e., *no quoting* - in PowerShell *Core* on *Unix-like platforms*, but never with a *quoted* string such as `"*.java"` or `'*.java'`, and even without quoting never on *Windows*).

**Apparently, [it is legacy versions of `java.exe` *on Windows* that automatically perform the globbing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31384767/45375) on *unquoted* arguments, in an apparent attempt to emulate the behavior of POSIX-like shells such as Bash on Unix.**

- As of (at least) JDK 12, this behavior no longer seems to be effect, at least not by default.
- The linked answer suggests that in earlier versions there *may* be a system property that controls the behavior, but it's *unclear what its name is*.

  - Generally, the syntax `java -D<systemPropName>=<value> ...` can be used to set a system property on startup.

Therefore, you have the following options:

- Upgrade to a Java version that no longer exhibits this behavior (by default).
- In legacy versions, find the relevant system property name that disables the behavior and use the syntax shown above.
- Use *shell-specific* quoting, as shown below.

---

#### Using quoting to prevent globbing:

To prevent `java.exe` from performing globbing, **the invocation command line must *ultimately* contain `"*.java"`, i.e., the  argument must be *enclosed in double quotes***.

Unfortunately, there is **no common syntax** that works in both PowerShell and `cmd.exe`:

**`cmd.exe`**:

`cmd.exe` passes double-quoted arguments through as-is, so the following is sufficient:

```
java Arguments "*.java"
```

**PowerShell**:

PowerShell, by contrast, performs *re-quoting as needed* behind the scenes (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51773694/45375) for more information).

Since an argument with content `*.java` normally does *not* require quoting when you pass it to an external program, **PowerShell translates both `"*.java"` and `'*.java'` to *unquoted* `*.java` in the command line that is *ultimately* used behind the scenes** - which is what you experienced.

There are two ways around that:

- Use `java Arguments '"*.java"'`, i.e., embed the `"` chars. in the argument, inside a literal string (`'...'`).
- Use `java Arguments --% "*.java"`; `--%` is the [stop-parsing symbol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing) (PSv3+), which instructs PowerShell to pass the remainder of the command line through as-is (except for expanding `cmd.exe`-style environment-variable references).