# powershell not expands variable as argument

Tags: powershell, variables, cmake, arguments

I've following commands in a powershell script:

```
$boostPath = "D:/lib/boost/1.62.0-vs2013-x64"
cmake -S $cmakeRootPath -B $buildPath -G $cmakeGenerator -DBOOST_ROOT=$boostPath
```

With this the variable `$boostPath` is not expanded. I can see in `FindBoost` log

```
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1528 ] BOOST_ROOT = "$boostPath"
```

Instead, if in the script I write

```
cmake -S $cmakeRootPath -B $buildPath -G $cmakeGenerator -DBOOST_ROOT="D:/lib/boost/1.62.0-vs2013-x64"
```

The variable is set correctly and cmake works. How can I give correctly the argument using a variable?

Comment: The PowerShell parser interprets the entire string `-DBOOST_ROOT=$boostPath` as a switch parameter. Use `-DBOOST_ROOT="$boostPath"` and it should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) has provided the crucial pointer in comment:

A token such as `-DBOOST_ROOT=$boostPath` is parsed as a *literal* by PowerShell - the `$boostPath` variable reference is *not* recognized and therefore not expanded (replaced by its value).

PowerShell's sometimes surprising behavior with unquoted compound token is summarized in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6467).

The following should *generally* work and *definitely* works if `$boostPath` contains *no spaces*:

```
cmake -S $cmakeRootPath -B $buildPath -G $cmakeGenerator -DBOOST_ROOT="$boostPath"
```

Double-quoting of the variable reference forces its expansion.

**Note**:

- Since PowerShell performs *re-quoting* behind the scenes that preserves double quotes (potentially converted from single quotes) only *if needed* (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51773694/45375)) and your path contains no spaces, what `cmake` will see on the command line is verbatim
  `-DBOOST_ROOT=D:/lib/boost/1.62.0-vs2013-x64` - no quotes.
- If `$boostPath` *did* contain spaces, say `$boostPath = "D:/lib 1/boost/1.62.0-vs2013-x64"`, PowerShell would double-quote the argument *as a whole*, so that what `cmake` will see on the command line is verbatim
  `"-DBOOST_ROOT=D:/lib 1/boost/1.62.0-vs2013-x64"`

  - If `cmake` on Windows<sup>[1]</sup> truly requires the `"..."` to be around the `$boostPath` value only (which some CLIs, notably `msiexec`,  unfortunately require), use this **workaround** (one argument omitted for brevity):

```
cmake -S $cmakeRootPath -B $buildPath -DBOOST_ROOT="`"$boostPath`""
```

**Caveat**: If PowerShell's broken (re)quoting of arguments passed to external programs (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375)) should ever get fixed (see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13068#issuecomment-653526374)), this workaround will *break*.

---

<sup>[1] Only on Windows do (console) programs need to do their own parsing of a whole *command line* into individual arguments; on *Unix-like* platforms, they sensibly receive an *array* of *verbatim* tokens.</sup>